# Android call activity integration inside chat interface

Tags: android, interface, chat, call, voip

I have an android VOIP app which works as follows.
Summary of the app-

1. The app once launched scans the WiFi to look for other android devices who have my app installed. (Note: The devices having my app installed should be connected to the same WiFi network).
2. Once the scan completes, it lists all the available devices. The user can click on any device and initiate call or chat.

   > After clicking on the user, an action dialog appears containing a positive button and a negative button. That is, **positive button = call** and
   >   **negative button = chat**.

Each button opens their respective interfaces when clicked.

My question is...

a. How can I integrate the call button inside the chat interface?
For example, I could make a toolbar and attach the call button to it.

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if you guys have any queries.

Comment: Let me get that straight: You do a network scan in a WLAN to set up a VOIP P2P? Given the diameter of the average WLAN I'd rather fall back to shouting rather risking a NIDS ringing the s... out of the admins...

Answer (score 1):

The call button, that is on top in the example image given, is a normal ActionBar MenuItem.

A good start to know more about Menus is the [Android Developer Guide website: Menus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)